# How can I indicate (briefly)in our Registration (signup) screen that they should use a different password from their email?

Tags: best-practice

We streamlined our signup to require only email and a password.

However, we think some users think we are asking for their email password.

I'm trying to think of ways to succinctly communicate that is NOT what we want.

So I'm thinking:

---

**App Registration**
Email Address:
Create New Password :  [                    ]
(Not your email password)

---

**App Registration**
Email Address:
Password :  [  (New password. Not your email password)  ]

**Update**

I realized, after reading some other related UX questions that we do not even need to ask for a password yet. That solves this immediate problem AND simplified registration

---

Create Free Account

Email address:

Then we email them (with temp password) a link.
Link  confirms the email addresss and lets them change password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I realized, after reading some other related UX questions:*

We do not even need to ask for a password at Registration time. That solves the immediate problem AND simplifies registration.

**App Registration**

Your Email Address: [         --------------    ]

**[Create Free Account]**

*Then we email them a temporary password and a link. The link confirms the email address and lets the user change the password.*

Comment: Yes,  if you must ask for it...  email address [         ],  Password for <site name> [          ]

Answer (score 1):

It's best to give a little context, a little tough to gauge without a wire-frame. But it may be possible to say it in a sentence, similar to what you have shown.

"Email address for login [] Password for App []."

Just making it clear that they are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just realised you say email password, not domain:

[image: Registration]

The most important thing is clear and precise instructions, sometimes it can feel wordy and as though it is messing up your design, but the user will benefit from less frustration.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you think that your users think that.

What evidence do you have that supports this?

Can you provide a screenshot of your registration page or more context on your product? Is your product linked to email services?

You may get better answers with more information.

Anyway, this is the approach I would take if your supposition is true:

Request a username/password combo. Thirdly, ask for an email after the password. This way the password is associated with the username, not the email.

[image: mockup]

I realize this may go against your streamlining work but messy text that tells the users what they should and shouldn't do can just as easily convolute the sign up process. Also, a single extra field at sign up is a small UX price to pay vs having to remember yet another password every time a user visits because you suggested it. As a matter of fact, what happens if I WANT to use my email password and ignore your suggestion. Then I may have an uneasy feeling about it and wonder if somehow I am vulnerable because of it.

That simple message you want to add could really be a significant violation of the "Don't make me think" principle.

In summary keep a normal sign up flow. Avoid any out of place language. Use the layout and fields to disassociate the email/password association you are worried about.

Comment: Now that I answered this, I am still wondering WHY you care what password they use. You may have standard criteria for an acceptable password... such as 8 characters, a cap and a number or symbol... but what combo they choose is up to the user. I say, let them have what ever password they want. No other app I know tells me what password I should or shouldn't use.

Comment: Our users are very very non technical (avg age of about 55 and many over 65) I have watched users use their email account password. I previously thought they were doing that for convenience (same password everywhere) but I now *suspect* that they think we want their email password.

Also, previously, when we previously asked for the info you suggest (we have since eliminated user name) people would ask "what is my password", suggesting that they thought they should already *have* the password.

Comment: Yeoch! Tough personas to design for... (not the age but the tech level) If there is no harm in letting them use the same password (ehem... I do), consider "letting" them...